# How to enable scheduled major compaction in Hbase?

Tags: hbase

I have a sequential inflow of data in hbase and I want to schedule the major compactions to happen in a particular time. I have configured the hbase-site.xml using the properties 'hbase.hregion.majorcompaction' and 'hbase.hregion.majorcompaction.jitter'. But the major compactions doesn't happen as per the configuration. 
This is the configuration for scheduled major compaction in my hbase-site.xml,

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction</name>      
    <value>300000</value> 
</property>

<property> 
    <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction.jitter</name>       
    <value>.50F</value> 
</property>
```

I have set the major compaction to happen every 5 minutes but it's not happening. Please suggest a way to schedule the major compaction.

Comment: did you restart hbase?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried restarting Hadoop too. But the major compaction didn't happend as I scheduled.